# Neo4j: Could not find java at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\bin\java.exe

Tags: java, neo4j

I am facing a problem while using Neo4j.

[image: Error]

I have on my PC:

- Java JDK 10
- Neo4j 3.4.5

Environment variable:

[image: Environment variables]

Comment: JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME need to be without "\bin" afaik

Comment: didn't work with me

Comment: Did you close and re-open the console after changing the variables?

Comment: Plese, don't answer your own question with an edit. Post an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved my issue by:

-Downgrading java jdk version

Answer (score 0):

No need to downgrade java. This worked for me:

1. Uninstall the neo4j service running **neo4j uninstall-service** from
   the bin subdirectory. Don't worry if you see *WARNING: Unable to determine Java Version*
2. Uninstall java
3. Reinstalled java
4. Reinstalled the neo4j service running **neo4j install-service** from
   the bin subdirectory.
5. Run **neo4j start**

You should not see the java warning in step 4 or 5.